# CSS Will not render via bundling, works fine if written directly on the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4

If I were to do inline style it works just fine, but if I attempt to link the CSS file within the `head` or put it in a bundle it won't render. This is running Locally and I have debug set to true on `Web.config` - `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />`

**Any ideas on what could be blocking this? Am I missing something here..** I've attached my `BundleConfig.cs`, note that I added `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` to `Global.asax.cs`.

Probably worth mentioning - when I load the page and its plain HTML with no styling, I try to manually retrieve that CSS file and get the following error; even though the file path the error outputs results in a valid path for me locally:

```
System.Web.HttpExceptionPath '/Content/site.css' was not found.

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Path '/Content/site.css' was not found.
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I added the following to my `Web.config` file since my project makes use of Simple authentication.

```
  <location path="~/Content" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Here's a screenshot of the project structure:

[image]

This is what my `BundleConfig.cs` looks like:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace MyProjectNamespace
{
    public static class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have for the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
   <div id ="accountbar">
        MORE HTML IN HERE.
   </div>
   <br />
   <div id ="loginform">
      @RenderBody() 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS file in Content directory, `site.css`:

```
  body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}  

  #loginform {
    background-color: #a4d4e6;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

  #accountbar {
    background-color: #778899;
}
```

Comment: Hitting the file locally and direct does not work? `http://localhost:XXXXX/content/style.css`

Comment: @mxmissile Check my question; I stated that I attempted to manually enter the CSS path and got back error. - `When I load the page and its plain HTML with no styling, I try to manually retrieve that CSS file and get the following error...`

Comment: Right, but you didn't mention this was local as in your dev machine, or a production server. Sorry I was not clear.

Comment: Check the path while debugging/testing.  Depending on whether you are working locally or off a server, discrepancy between local and absolute paths could be the cause.

Comment: By chance does it work if you remove the authentication?

Comment: @mxmissile Updated question, this is Local development and I have `debug=true` within `Web.config`.

Comment: Start simple, have you verified that your bundle config code is being called from global.asax?

Comment: @Brocco I just stepped through the code, verified that the bundles are indeed getting loaded but still no go; HTML is stripped of any CSS. It Still makes me wonder - Why can't I access the CSS file via the browser. I have a feeling this is all just permission issues... I'm being denied access to that Content directory.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to hit the bundle directly in the browser? The status code of the error will direct where to go next.

Comment: What is the Build Action set to on style.css? (Properties)

Comment: @mxmissile Build action for site.css - `Content`

Comment: Is your project on a shared (network) drive?

Comment: @mxmissile Its not shared drive, and just to be safe I went ahead and copied the project folder to my desktop and did a clean build and rebuild all - No luck.

Comment: Try renaming your bundle to a name that doesn't reference an actual physical directory, like "~/ContentBundle/sitecss". You'll have to change web.config to allow it, the script definition and reference in the aspx page.

Comment: @Brocco I renamed the bundle name but left it pointing to `"~/Content/site.css"`, didn't see any difference. What did you mean by - "You'll have to change web.config to allow it, the script definition and reference in the aspx page."

Comment: I meant changing <location path="~/Content" allowOverride="false"> to <location path="~/ContentBundle" allowOverride="false"> if you were still using it

Comment: @Brocco Just did, `Location element is unused: no project item found at ContentBundle` it tried to look within `~\Web\ContentBundle`.

Answer (score 0):

If you think this is a permissions issue, have you considered using the authorize attribute on your controllers/actions instead of specifically allowing access to the CSS?

I find that in MVC 4 you get some really unexpected results if you try to use the system.web authorization (especially if you are already also using the authorize attribute).

I have often banged my head against weird authorization issues like this and from looking at my current projects I am using an integrated application pool in IIS and have added the following to the web.config under system.webServer:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

HTH